# RStudio Server from Windows Subsystem for Linux cannot find packages on PATH

Tags: r, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rstudio-server, bedtools

I am trying to use RStudio Server to run a package (CNV-CLinViewer) through Windows Subsystem for Linux.
All R packages required could be installed except for `bedtoolsr`, which requires `bedtools` (not an R package). I have `bedtools` installed on my WSL and the folder is part of my PATH.

For some reason, RStudio does not "see" it, however.
I tried to manually set the path to bedtools using `options(bedtools.path = "/home/usr/anaconda3/bin/bedtools")`, but that did not help either.

Does anybody have a tip on how to make it visible to RStudio Server?

Thanks

Comment: Which PATH variable did you change? Both Windows and your WSL OS will have it's own PATH environment variable. Make sure you update the one in WSL. And then make sure you relaunch the server after the update so it will inherit the new environment variable.

Comment: I did not change anything on my windows. I use RStudio exclusively on WSL.

Comment: So if you run `Sys.getenv("PATH")` from your RStudio session, do you see the value you expect? If not, how exactly did you set your PATH?

Comment: It does not. For some reason, it does not update it. I did try to restart the server. How do I change this behaviour?

Comment: You really haven't provided a lot of details on what exactly you are doing. How are you getting the PATH variable? How are you launching the server? Are you doing both in the same terminal session?

Comment: The PATH variable from the terminal differs from the one returned by RStudio when I run `Sys.getend("PATH")`.
From terminal: `/home/analyst/anaconda3/bin:/home/analyst/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/analyst/.dotnet/tools`

From RStudio: `"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/postback:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/postback:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/postback"`

Server launched from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the PATH variable was on RStudio was different from the one displayed on the terminal (it was missing `/home/analyst/anaconda3/bin`).

Editing the PATH variable on RStudio fixed it. I edited the variable like this:
`old_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")`

`Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(old_path, "/home/analyst/anaconda3/bin", sep = ":"))`